# I need a PopUpPage that disappear when clicking out side it's window

Tags: popup

I'm using the sharepoint js function `OpenPopUpPage` which is working just great, requirements changed, and now the customer want the pop-up page to be closed if user clicked outside the pop-up page's window rather than click on the close button..
any possibleties to achieve this using `OpenPopUpPage`? or any other alternative popups?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gray surface behind you popup is a div with the class 'ms-dlgOverlay', so after calling OpenPopUpPage you can set the onclick event to close the dialog.

Here is a javascript function which wraps OpenPopUpPage and does that:

```
function MyOpenPopUpPage(url, callback, width, height){
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage(url, callback, width, height);

  // Find ms-dlgOverlay
  var overlay = null;
  var $v_1 = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var $v_2 = 0; $v_2 < $v_1.length; $v_2++) {
    var $v_3 = $v_1[$v_2];
    if ($v_3.className.indexOf('ms-dlgOverlay') !== -1){
      overlay = $v_3;
      break;
    }
  }
  // Set click to close
  if (overlay) {
    overlay.setAttribute('onclick','SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(0);');
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Works great, just need to remove the `return false;` :)

Comment: Can we let the pop-up takes its Width/Height automatically from its content (image, for example)?

Comment: The function behaves like the original OpenPopUpPage, so if you don't specify width and height it'll try to size automatically.

Comment: The test shows that The `OpenPopUpPage` doesn't automatically re-sized according to its content! I don't know why

Comment: Auto resizing will only work if the page being shown: Includes SP.UI.Dialog.js, knows how big it is and is in the same domain so it can send the infomation to the main window without running into XSS problems